# how do we read total amount earned from adsense using its api

Tags: google-adsense

I want to display the total amount earned at the right top corner of my desktop if there is any api provided with adsense so that i can use a window application to fetch that information from google. is there any thing available like that?

where can i get examples. sample codes.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Google Adsense API](http://code.google.com/apis/adsense/developer/index.html)

Comment: But that was too generic.

Comment: any code sample references?